# Sqlite code not displaying any Debug log?

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

Very new to sqlLite and trying to make a very simple bit of code which will display the values of username and password in the table just using the debug log for ease. When running the code nothing is display in the debug log. Could someone suggest a fix?

```
     IDbConnection dbconn;
     dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(conn);
     dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
     IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
     string sqlQuery = "SELECT username, password " + "FROM user";
     dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
     IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         string username = reader.GetString(0);
         string password = reader.GetString(1);
        
        
         Debug.Log("Username: " + username + "  Password:" + password);
     }
     reader.Close();
     reader = null;
     dbcmd.Dispose();
     dbcmd = null;
     dbconn.Close();
     dbconn = null;
 }
   }
```

Comment: Do you get the log at all? Can you confirm that it even enters the loop?

Comment: i dont get any log at all, potentially it does not enter the loop what would i do to test this?

Comment: [**Debug your code**! with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) .. also note that if this is on a background thread and there happens an exception you might not get any exception displayed in the log. Rather wrap your code in `try{ ... } catch(Exception e) { Debug.LogException(e); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the parameter out of the reader like that:

```
 IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         string username = reader["username"];
         string password = reader["password"]
        
        
         Debug.Log("Username: " + username + "  Password:" + password);
     }
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, i get an error cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'